# node.js crypto pbkdf2 return undefined

Tags: node.js, cryptojs

```
export const upgradeBase64crypto = (password) => {
    crypto.randomBytes(64, (err, buf) => {
        const salt = buf.toString("base64");
      
        crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, 100, 64, "sha512", (err, key) => {
            return key.toString("base64");
        });
    });
};

import { upgradeBase64crypto } from "../../../utils/pwCrypto";

export default {
    Mutation: {
        signUpUser: async (_, args, { request, query }) => {
            try {
                const param = args.param;
                let pw = upgradeBase64crypto(param.pw);
              
                console.log(pw);
            } 
          catch (err) {}
        },
    },
};
```

When running `console.log(key.toString('base64'))` in `upgradeBase64crypto`, the normally encrypted string appears in the log. However, running `return key.toString('base64')` returns `undefined`. What's the problem?

Comment: What's the value of 'args.param'? Did you debug it?

Comment: It is certain that there is a password string. I checked. It will encrypt properly when running console.log instead of return. However, if you run a return, the value is not returned.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not returning any value from the `upgradeBase64crypto` function. Try:

```
export const upgradeBase64crypto = (password) => {
    let passwordHash;

    crypto.randomBytes(64, (err, buf) => {
        const salt = buf.toString('base64');
        
        passwordHash = crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, 100, 64, 'sha512', (err, key) => {
            return key.toString('base64');
        });
    });

    return passwordHash;
}
```

EDIT:

Sorry, missed the callback wrapping. This will solve your problem:

```
const upgradeBase64crypto = (password) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {        
        crypto.randomBytes(64, (err, buf) => {
            const salt = buf.toString('base64');

            crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, 100, 64, 'sha512', (err, key) => {
                resolve(key.toString('base64'));
            });
        })
    });
}
```

Previously you were trying to access the value before the callback's had the opportunity to set it as you're using the `async` versions of the `crypto` methods. Now it returns a promise. You'll need to `.then` or `await` the operation in your `signUpUser` method:

```
signUpUser: async (_, args, { request, query }) => {
    try {
        const param = args.param;
        let pw = await upgradeBase64crypto(param.pw);

        console.log(pw);
    }
    catch(error) { }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running this code yourself? I don't return the value of this code either.

Comment: @LEE.SANG.MIN Sorry, my bad. I've made an edit.

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much. I think I need to learn a little bit more about asynchronous mode.

Comment: How to save salt in this configuration? I wish to save the Salt in my own MongoDB schema, just need a way to save the specific one using your setup here. Thanks!